# Angular material custom toast not closing properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code to create angular material toast. I am having weird issue when click close button. When i click the close button it closes in frames ie. the span which has got the text gets closed and then the main  gets closed. Not sure what am i doing wrong.

My code:

```
<md-toast ng-if="messageState.getNoRecordsMessage()" class="toast-container toast-success">
   <span class="md-toast-text" flex>{{messageState.getNoRecordsMessage()}}</span> 
   <md-button ng-click="closeToast()">
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="close" class="white-font"></md-icon>
   </md-button>
</md-toast>

<md-toast ng-if="messageState.getErrorMessage()" class="toast-container toast-error">
   <span flex> {{messageState.getErrorMessage()}} <br> Please contact your system administrator if the error persists. </span> 
   <md-button ng-click="closeToast()" class="white-font">
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="close"></md-icon>
   </md-button>
</md-toast>

<md-toast ng-if="messageState.getSuccessMessage()" class="toast-container toast-success">
   <span flex>{{messageState.getSuccessMessage()}}</span> 
   <md-button ng-click="closeToast()">
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="close" class="white-font"></md-icon>
   </md-button>
</md-toast>
```

And the close function is:

```
            $scope.closeToast = function () {
                $mdToast
                    .hide()
                    .then(function () {
                        $scope.messageState.setSuccessMessage("");
                    })
            }
```

Can anyone figure out what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help from [documentation page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast), have an extra check if the dialog is open, not sure is it your issue.

```
$scope.closeToast = function() {
    if (isDlgOpen) return;

    $mdToast
      .hide()
      .then(function() {
        isDlgOpen = false;
        $scope.messageState.setSuccessMessage("");
      });
  };
```